# Load container events after ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events

### #

Update: see answer at the end of the question

### #

I am experiencing the follow issue:

I created a function to load all the events/plugins that get loaded on a specific event. When the page initially load this gets loaded on "body" when an ajax call is made the container where the content gets loaded into is then called.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.defaultFormValues = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            var element = $(this);

            var defaultValue = element.attr("default");
            var currentValue = element.val();

            // This will make sure not to replace exisitng values
            if( !currentValue ) {
                element.val( defaultValue ).addClass('input-before-focus');
            }
            else if( currentValue == defaultValue ) {
                element.addClass('input-before-focus');
            }

            element.unbind('focus').bind('focus', function() {
                if( element.val() == defaultValue ) {
                    element.val('').removeClass('input-before-focus');
                }
            });

            element.unbind('blur').bind('blur', function() {
                var currentVal = element.val();

                if( currentVal == '' ) {
                    element.val(defaultValue).addClass('input-before-focus');
                }
            });
        }); // end function
    };
})( jQuery );

(function($){
    $.fn.loadEvents = function(){
        return this.each(function(){

            var containerObj = $(this);

            $("input[default], textarea[default]",containerObj).defaultFormValues();
        });
    };
})( jQuery );
```

I load the initial call like so:

```
$("body").loadEvents();
```

When the ajax container gets loaded it loads the events like this:

```
container.loadEvents();
```

---

For some reason the events don't work for the ajax call.

Any help would be appreciated.

Alexander

- - - - Answer

Ok I was able to figure out the issue. Whenever you utilize container.replaceWith(…) the reference to the element "container" is no longer available as it has been deleted and replaced with a new instance of that element.

It is a logic item that I have simply missed, in case any one is running into the same issue.

Alexander

Comment: when and where do you call `defaultFormValues` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you add new elemnts using `load()` or othe insertion method...you will need to call your method after those elements are inserted.

Very simplest case would be

```
$('#content').load('path/to/server',function(){
/* new content exists, can bind event handlers to it*/
  $(this).loadEvents()
});
```